# How to find data in array of object in mongodb that have different order?

Tags: mongodb

I have data in collection in mongodb like this :

```
[
{
    _id  : "ObjectId(1)",
    name : "data1",
    data : [
        { text: "a", value: 1 },
        { text: "b", value: 2 }
    ]
},
{
    _id  : "ObjectId(2)",
    name : "data2",
    data : [
        { text: "b", value: 2 },
        { text: "a", value: 1 }
    ]
}
]
```

like you see, `data1` and `data2` have same `data` but different order.

I need to find in this `db.somecol.find({})` that return all document with same `data` that ignore order in array.

how to do that?

I try using `$elemMatch` but it can't.

Comment: `that return all document with same data` - a bit confused by this statement, So  do you've any inputs to match with or do we need to scan all documents in collection to get documents which has matching objects in `data` array, I guess mostly it's with inputs `{ text: "b", value: 2 },
        { text: "a", value: 1 }`, can you just confirm - Also if it's the case do you need all inputs to exist in `data` array or any one object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/index.html) operator which will check all inputs exists in array irrespective of order.

```
db.somecol.find({
    data: {
        $all: [{
            "text": "a",
            "value": 1.0
        },
        {
            "text": "b",
            "value": 2.0
        }]
    }
})
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "ObjectId(1)",
    "name" : "data1",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "text" : "a",
            "value" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "b",
            "value" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "ObjectId(2)",
    "name" : "data2",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "text" : "b",
            "value" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "a",
            "value" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */ /** This will not be returned in result */
{
    "_id" : "ObjectId(3)",
    "name" : "data1",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "text" : "a",
            "value" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "b",
            "value" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "ObjectId(1)",
    "name" : "data1",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "text" : "a",
            "value" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "b",
            "value" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "ObjectId(2)",
    "name" : "data2",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "text" : "b",
            "value" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "a",
            "value" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To scan whole collection to get documents which has matching objects in data array:

### Explanation

I assume `_id` is unique and ordered index

1. We iterate over the same collection with `$lookup`. We filter all values greater than id <sub>i</sub>.
2. Next step, we add 3 fields:

   **same_size**: check if data(i) == data(j)
   **order1**   : check if all data(j) elements are inside data(j) 
   it returns item(j) index [0, 1, ...]

   **order2**   : check if all data(j) elements are inside data(i)

   - it returns item(j) index inside data(i) [1, 0, ...] or [0, 1, ...]
   - If not $indexOfArray returns -1
3. Next step, we filter:

   (same_size == true) and (-1 not in order2) and (concat(order1) != concat(order2))
4. We remove our extra fields and final match to ignore empty `differentOrder` array

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        id: "$_id",
        data: "$data"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $gt: [
                    "$_id",
                    "$$id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            same_size: {
              $eq: [
                {
                  $size: "$data"
                },
                {
                  $size: "$$data"
                }
              ]
            },
            order1: {
              $map: {
                input: "$data",
                in: {
                  $indexOfArray: [
                    "$data",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            order2: {
              $map: {
                input: "$data",
                in: {
                  $indexOfArray: [
                    "$$data",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$same_size",
                    true
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $not: {
                    $in: [
                      -1,
                      "$order2"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  $ne: [
                    {
                      $reduce: {
                        input: "$order1",
                        initialValue: "",
                        in: {
                          $concat: [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                              $toString: "$$this"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      $reduce: {
                        input: "$order2",
                        initialValue: "",
                        in: {
                          $concat: [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                              $toString: "$$this"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unset: [
            "order1",
            "order2",
            "same_size"
          ]
        }
      ],
      as: "differentOrder"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "differentOrder.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/grhQX53_DJx